# Is there a mathematical explanation for the Aharonov-Casher effect?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-cohomology, line-bundles, connections, curvature

Recall that the [Aharonov-Bohm effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov-Bohm_effect) can be interpreted mathematically as follows.

Consider an electromagnetic field A on some smooth manifold M, i.e., A is an element in the first differential cohomology of M, or in other words, an isomorphism class of complex hermitian line bundles with a metric connection over M.

The field strength of A is defined to be its curvature.
It can happen that the field strength is zero, i.e., a charged particle traveling through M has no forces acting on it, yet we can still observe a nontrivial change in phase if the particle travels around a loop with a nontrivial holonomy.
This change of phase can then be observed in a physical experiment.

In other words, a line bundle with connection can be flat without being trivial, in particular, it can have nontrivial holonomy.

Recently I learned that there is a dual (in a certain physical sense) effect to the Aharonov-Bohm effect,
namely, the [Aharonov-Casher effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov-Casher_effect),
in which a charged particle is replaced by a neutral particle with a magnetic moment.

**Can we interpret the Aharonov-Casher effect mathematically in a similar way to the Aharonov-Bohm effect?**

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference between the effects. As you are writing, A is an *electromagentic field*, and the particle is charged under it. Whether field or particle are purely electrical or magnetical depends on the choice of a reference frame, and I am tempted to say that it can thus be considered irrelevant. 

Comment: @Waldorf, no matter what frame you are in the particle is neutral.

Comment: @Chris Gerig: Note that the particle in the AC effect is supposed to have a magnetic moment. So it is *not* neutral with respect to the electromagentic field A. 

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant relativistic frames where E-fields or B-fields disappear. But yes, the main difference here is that either the particle carries a charge or it carries a moment, and both can be considered to interact with A, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same mathematical effect (from reading their paper on it):

The action-functional is effectively (ignoring kinetic term) $\bar{v}\cdot \bar{E}\times\bar{\mu}$. But this is equivalent to the precession of the magnetic moment in a magnetic field, $\bar{E}\times\bar{\mu}=e\bar{A}$ (a paper of Kan and Koh, 1992, actually explains this in great detail). From here the Lagrangian for the AC-effect is effectively the Lagrangian for the AB-effect, and is due to the vector potential... this is what the *dual* aspect is.

*Clarification*: In fact, their paper came across this effect by simply manipulating the view of the AB-effect in the case of a solenoid (the standard example). A solenoid can be represented as a bunch of magnetic moments lined up, and this is what they do to get the AC-effect. They explicitly attribute this to the vector potential, quote, "*Is it possible to generate a situation in which a neutral particle exhibits the A-B effect? We will show that
this is indeed possible and is actually a necessary consequence of the physics described by Eq. (1).*" Equation 1 here is the standard Lagrangian for particle motion, and involves the vector potential (that *is* how you get a potential term in the Lagrangian).

*Aside*: This is related to how us physics students learn [in Electrodynamics] that the only physical quantities are the E-field and B-field, and the vector potential $A$ and scalar potential $\phi$ are simply mathematical constructs to help computations... this is indeed true, as the electromagnetic field is described by virtual photons. Yet the AB-effect (and hence AC-effect) shows how through the vector potential we realize a topological condition on our fields!

Comment: I wonder why physicists would make such a big deal out of it (and write several papers about it) if it is merely a change in the coordinate system.  In particular, I don't understand why a mere change in the coordinate system would require an independent experimental confirmation, as claimed in this article, for example: http://www.atomwave.org/rmparticle/ao%20refs/aifm%20refs%20sorted%20by%20topic/Topological%20phases/a-c%20effect%20theory/Boyer.pdft

Comment: No, the math is the same, the physics is different. The topological phase comes about due to the vector potential A mathematically, but this achieved in two different ways... One via an electric charge, one via a magnetic moment.

Comment: But it's still merely a choice of the reference frame, isn't it?  Won't an observer moving at relativistic speeds observe AB effect as AC and vice versa?

Comment: No, because the particle will never gain a charge...

Comment: @Chris: How can this be reconciled with Konrad's claim (to which you apparently agreed) that being electrically charged or having a magnetic moment depends on the reference frame?

Comment: We were just clarifying that regardless of the E- or B-field, the magnetic moment will interact (or the charge will interact, depending on which particle we're considering). "Reference frame" in that sense wasn't meaning move at a speed (which is what I originally thought when he made the comment, and then said 'sorry' after).